# Fetch a list from a dictionary based on a nested value?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a dictionary:

```
episode = {
    "translations": [{
        "language": {
            "code": "de"
        },
        "title": "German"
    }, {
        "language": {
            "code": "en"
        },
        "title": "English"
    }, {
        "language": {
            "code": "fr"
        },
        "title": "French"
    }]
};
```

I would like to get specifically the list that matches a specific language code. I could walk through the entire dictionary using the following code:

```
            for translation in episode['translations']:
                if translation['language']['code'] == 'fr':
                    language = translation;
                    break;
```

But that seems a bit excessive, and a waste of resources. Is there a better way of doing this, without having to walk through the entire array?

Comment: Your code is the best you can do with the data structure, as is. If this is something you filter on often, I'd suggest making translations a dict, using "code" as the key.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is stored in a list, then the only way to extract queries based on a condition is to iterate over the entries. In the snippet you provide, the implicit assumption of using `break` is that there is a unique entry of interest (or perhaps the first match is of interest).

For more optimal queries of this data, it should be transformed to a different  structure. For example, it's possible to convert it to a `pandas` dataframe or convert the data to a dictionary where keys are `translation['language']['code']` (so look-ups become `O(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Short of modifying how you structured your data*, I don't see a way that doesn't involve traversing the whole dictionary. That being said, there are a few more elegant ways to do it, although elegance is highly subjective:

`filter(lambda x: 'fr' in x['language'].values(), episode['translations'])`

would give you an iterable that contains all the the entries in your dictionary that have the required language code. Calling `next` on it would give you the first one, for instance.

Edit:

* what SultanOrazbayev proposed in their answer is one such way to modify your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is neater although not really different from the original code except that it allows for more than one dictionary entry having a particular code. For example:

```
episode = {
    "translations": [{
        "language": {
            "code": "de"
        },
        "title": "German"
    }, {
        "language": {
            "code": "en"
        },
        "title": "English"
    }, {
        "language": {
            "code": "fr"
        },
        "title": "French"
    }]
}
list_ = [d for d in episode['translations'] if d['language']['code'] == 'en']
print(list_)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'language': {'code': 'en'}, 'title': 'English'}]
```